# Der Satzbau eines Satz von Kafka, in dem »auch das Gesicht breit« steht

Tags: sentence-structure

In dieser Frage geht es um »auch das Gesicht breit« im folgenden Auszug aus *Das Schloß* von Kafka, wie betont:

> K. hatte sie wohl lange angesehn, dieses sich nicht verändernde schöne traurige Bild, dann aber mußte er eingeschlafen sein, denn als er von einer lauten Stimme gerufen, aufschreckte, lag sein Kopf an der Schulter des Alten neben ihm. Die Männer hatten ihr Bad, in dem sich jetzt die Kinder von der blonden Frau beaufsichtigt herumtrieben, beendet und standen angezogen vor K. Es zeigte sich daß der schreierische Vollbärtige der Geringere von den zweien war. Der andere nämlich, nicht größer als der Vollbärtige und mit viel geringerem Bart, war ein stiller, langsam denkender Mann, von breiter Gestalt, **auch das Gesicht breit**, den Kopf hielt er gesenkt.

**FRAGE**

1. Gehört die Phrase zu dem Satz, der ihr vorangeht oder nachgeht?
2. Ist sie ein [Absolutes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_construction)?

**HINTERGRUND**

Im zweiten Fall haben wir:

> Auch das Gesicht breit, den Kopf hielt er gesenkt.

Das Verb aber steht nicht an der zweiten Stelle. Oder ein Absolutes (wenn die Phrase eines ist) ausfüllt keine Stelle, das Verb steht an der zweiten Stelle, also ist der Satz richtig?

Vielleicht ist der erste Fall auch richtig:

> Der andere nämlich, nicht größer als der Vollbärtige und mit viel geringerem Bart, war ein stiller, langsam denkender Mann, von breiter Gestalt, auch das Gesicht breit.

In diesem Satz kann die Phrase auch nur ein Absolutes sein, denn »von« verlangt Dativ, und »das Gesicht« ist Nominativ oder Akkusativ.

Comment: Was genau meinst du mit »ein Absolutes«? Es gibt absolute Verben, aber im Zusammenhang mit Phrasen ist mir der Begriff *Absolut* absolut fremd.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast. I am thinking of things like a genitive absolute, accusative absolute etc. Maybe my terminology in German was wrong? See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accusative_absolute Also, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_construction

Comment: On the 'close' votes, I cannot imagine the idea of a phrase belonging to one independent clause or another is unclear to anyone. If the source of the problem is the "absolute," please see the links in the comment above. If I have worded it wrong in German, please someone kindly rephrase that part of the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ich habe zwar keine Ahnung, was du mit dem Begriff »Absolut« meinst, aber den Satz, der die fragliche Phrase enthält, könnte man auch wie folgt schreiben. (Ich habe den Satz in drei Sätze zerlegt, und ein paar Wörter eingefügt.)

> Der andere nämlich, nicht größer als der Vollbärtige und mit viel geringerem Bart, war ein stiller, langsam denkender Mann. **Er war** von breiter Gestalt, auch das Gesicht **war** breit. Den Kopf hielt er gesenkt.

Bitte beachte auch: *Das Schloss* hat Kafka im Jahr 1922 geschrieben, also vor fast 100 Jahren. Das heutige Deutsch ist ein wenig anders als das von 1922. Außerdem hat sich Kafka auch herzlich wenig um irgendwelche Standards gekümmert. Kafkas Deutsch war schon zu seinen Lebzeiten ein wenig anders als das Deutsch, das man damals z.B. in Zeitungen verwendete.

Comment: I think you are telling me that "auch das Gesicht breit" is a third independent clause with an implicit (unrealized) verb.  That makes perfect grammatical sense to me. (The semantics of the situation, viz. a face's being subordinate to the man, must have predisposed me to see a subordinate relationship between the two sentence-parts.)

Comment: @Catomic: Nachdem du die Frage auf Deutsch gestellt hast (Vielen Dank!) möchte ich die Diskussion dazu auch gerne auf Deutsch führen. Ich verstehe leider den Satz, den du in Klammern geschrieben hast nicht. (»The semantics ...«) Kannst du diesen Satz bitte ins Deutsche übersetzen, oder zumindest anders formulieren. Ich bin nämlich nicht so gut in Englisch.

Comment: Ich dachte:  "Das Gesicht gehört dem Mann. Also gehört die Phrase über das Gesicht dem Satz über den Mann!" Dumm von mir.